# mongoid admin with hash and array field types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-admin

I'm using rails_admin with mongoid but seems this gem has no support for editing hash/array field types. it just put the content crashed inside a textarea.

anyone knows an admin tool that have support for this field types? maybe rails active_admin or another language?

Comment: Did you manage to work around this issue somehow?

Comment: I didn't found any tool and made my app with nested form approach. Take a look here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Answer (score 0):

you need display Hash object as Json that present in RailsAdmin datatypes
here is my PR
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/pull/3103